# Getting diff between top two revisions of a file in CVS

Tags: diff, cvs

Is there way to create the diff of a file b/w its top two revisions in the CVS repo? I doesn't care about the revision numbers and my local checked-out file. All I need is, the diff b/w the last commit and the last before commit.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use

```
cvs diff -r FIRSTREVISION -r SECONDREVISION filename
```

to compare two revisions.

It may be possible to do the comparison you require directly, but we can also automate it by processing the results of `cvs log filename`.  So, for example, you get the latest revision number with

```
cvs log filename | grep ^revision | head -n 1 | cut -c 10-
```

and the previous revision with

```
cvs log filename | grep ^revision | head -n 2 | tail -n 1 | cut -c 10-
```

You want to merge these together, so create a BASH script file (say called *lastdiff.sh*) that contains:

```
cvs diff -r $(cvs log $1 | grep ^revision | head -n 2 | tail -n 1 | cut -c 10-) -r $(cvs log $1 | grep ^revision | head -n 1 | cut -c 10-) $1
```

and then you'll be able to get your diff by executing it with the filename as a parameter, e.g. `./lastdiff.sh` filename.

Comment: This is very useful. But is there a way to make this work for code committed to branch. With the above solution I am able to get the diff between 1.1 and 1.2 but I want to take a diff between 1.1 and 1.1.2.1.

Answer (score 1):

I had hoped there was an obvious cvs option I was missing, but borrible's scripted solution seems to be it.  If for whatever reason you're still using cvs, you might find this refinement useful:

```
cvs diff $(cvs log $FILE |
grep "^revision" |
sed "s/^revision/-r/
2q") $FILE
```

This uses sed to both grab the two latest revisions from a single invocation of "cvs log" and create the -r options directly from that output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cvs diff` to find out the differences between the local checked out version and the version present on the head.

```
cvs diff -r ver1 -r ver2 <FILE-NAME>
```